Upgrading issue from Ubuntu 22.04.5LTS to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
After upgrading all the packages in Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, I rebooted the machine.
Then, I updated the sources.lst and used the following command:
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

I am struck at the following error.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Error!
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcrypt1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

How can I fix this issue?
Note: I used the option "arch=amd64" in my sources.lst.

The command apt dist-upgrade is not the command to upgrade from one release to another; as the dist-upgrade is just an upgrade command with fewer restrictions; do-release-upgrade and release upgrade tools will upgrade a release.  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS does contain a package that meets your listed rule, ie. libc6 | 2.39-0ubuntu8.3  | noble-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x which you'll note includes the i386 package too.  Your question also has you trying to change from 22.04.5 to 22.04.1; both are 22.04 so it makes little sense (the .1 just has fewer fixes)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades  if that's what you're trying to do (your title implies that; though its not what your question tries to do)

The Ubuntu 22.04 version was using some 32-bit library and when I used the option "arch=amd64" in my sources.lst, it was unable  to upgrade the package. Once I removed the option, the upgradation worked.
